Pass custom flag to mina ssh server via ssh command
I want to run the ssh command in the following way:
ssh user@host "my_custom_flag=myValue"

Then in my java application where I have implemented the ssh server(apache mina) I want to be able to read the value of "my_custom_flag". Is it possible to achieve this kind of behavior?
